# Удалить блок со страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
function DeleteUserContent(idNote, IdCategory, idToUser){
    var el = $(this);
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {idNote : idNote, IdCategory : IdCategory, idToUser : idToUser},
             url: '/Delete',
             success: function(data) {
                    $(el).closest('div').remove();
             }
         });  
}
```

Не сработала инструкция: `$(el).closest('div').remove();`
Клик произошел по `<span onclick="DeleteUserContent()"></span>`

Comment: а какое было ожидаемое действие ? исключите ajax запрос (если хотите замените его на timeOut) и сделайте jsfiddle.

Comment: Должен был удалиться блок со страницы  $(el).closest('div').remove();

Comment: Что такое `$(el).closest('div')` ? 

а вообще это вам в наказание за onclick в разметке, - контекстом такого вызова будет window

иными словами - **не объявляйте события в разметке, особенно если используете jQuery**

Comment: @eicto хотел сказать, что вам нужно переделать способ вызова функции. Например на такой:

html:

    <span class="DeleteUserContent"></span>

js:

    $('.DeleteUserContent').on('click', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {idNote : idNote, IdCategory : IdCategory, idToUser : idToUser},
            url: '/Delete',
            success: function(data) {
                $(el).closest('div').remove();
            }
        });  
    });

Comment: я всё забываю сказать там $(el) не осмысленно

Comment: @eicto тогда следует в ajax запрос добавить:

    context: this

http://jsfiddle.net/8SCBB/1/ убери этот параметр и увидишь, что не будет работать.

Comment: я говорю про $(el) а не var el=$(this); просто el будет работать

Comment: @eicto а, не заметил.

Comment: Если оставить все как есть с вызовом по onclick, тогда как быть

Comment: нужно сделать так: onclick="DeleteUserContent(this)" т.е. передать контекст элемента в функцию.